# org.mybatis.cdi.MybatisCdiConfigurationException: There are no SqlSessionFactory producers properly configured

Tags: java, glassfish, cdi, mybatis

In use mybatis cdi 1.3 when it came to a question。

My development environment,up to date Payara,mybatis 3.3.0,mybatis cdi 1.0.0-beta3

my code:

```
@Stateless
public class SqlSessionFactoryProvider {

    private SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;

    @Named("sqlSession")
    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public SqlSessionFactory createSqlSessionFactory() throws IOException {
        String resource = "cn/mybatic/config/mybatis-config.xml";
        InputStream inputStream = Resources.getResourceAsStream(resource);
        sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(inputStream, "");
        return sqlSessionFactory;
    }

}
```

server:

```
@Stateless
public class UserService {

    private @Inject
    @LaPu
    EntityManager pmsQuery;

   // private @Inject @Mapper @Named("sqlSession") UserRepository userRepository;
    private @Named("sqlSession")
    @Inject
    SqlSession sqlSession;

    public void create(LaUser laUser) throws LaUserException {
        UserRepository userRepository = sqlSession.getMapper(UserRepository.class);
        LaUser oldLaUser = userRepository.getLaUser(laUser.getUsername());
        if (oldLaUser != null) {
            throw new LaUserException("");

        }
        pmsQuery.persist(laUser);
    }

}
```

or

```
@Stateless
public class UserService {

    private @Inject
    @LaPu
    EntityManager pmsQuery;


    private @Inject @Mapper @Named("sqlSession") UserRepository userRepository;

   // private @Inject SqlSession sqlSession;

    public void create(LaUser laUser) throws LaUserException {
       // UserRepository userRepository = sqlSession.getMapper(UserRepository.class);
        LaUser oldLaUser = userRepository.getLaUser(laUser.getUsername());
        if (oldLaUser != null) {
            throw new LaUserException("");

        }
        pmsQuery.persist(laUser);
    }

}
```

I have checked the configuration file is no problem，In the case without cd it is easy to use！

exception :

```
avax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:435)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2579)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1971)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy246.create(Unknown Source)
    at cn.ee.laboratory.laboratory.service.__EJB31_Generated__UserService__Intf____Bean__.create(Unknown Source)
    at cn.ee.laboratory.laboratory.view.UserAction.saveAction(UserAction.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter.doFilter(GzipResponseFilter.java:173)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:700)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:246)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:431)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:514)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:97)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:698)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.mybatis.cdi.MybatisCdiConfigurationException: There are no SqlSessionFactory producers properly configured.
    at org.mybatis.cdi.CDIUtils.findSqlSessionFactory(CDIUtils.java:53)
    at org.mybatis.cdi.MyBatisBean.findSqlSessionManager(MyBatisBean.java:129)
    at org.mybatis.cdi.MyBatisBean.create(MyBatisBean.java:115)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:761)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:861)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:375)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:386)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector$1.proceed(DefaultInjector.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:172)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:73)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.StatelessSessionBeanInjector.inject(StatelessSessionBeanInjector.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ejb.SessionBeanInjectionTarget.inject(SessionBeanInjectionTarget.java:140)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.injectEJBInstance(JCDIServiceImpl.java:257)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.injectEjbInstance(BaseContainer.java:1748)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:475)
    ... 67 more

警告:   /index.xhtml @26,111 actionListener="#{userAction.saveAction()}": javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml @26,111 actionListener="#{userAction.saveAction()}": javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter.doFilter(GzipResponseFilter.java:173)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:435)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2579)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1971)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy246.create(Unknown Source)
    at cn.ee.laboratory.laboratory.service.__EJB31_Generated__UserService__Intf____Bean__.create(Unknown Source)
    at cn.ee.laboratory.laboratory.view.UserAction.saveAction(UserAction.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:700)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:246)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:431)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:514)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:97)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:698)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.mybatis.cdi.MybatisCdiConfigurationException: There are no SqlSessionFactory producers properly configured.
    at org.mybatis.cdi.CDIUtils.findSqlSessionFactory(CDIUtils.java:53)
    at org.mybatis.cdi.MyBatisBean.findSqlSessionManager(MyBatisBean.java:129)
    at org.mybatis.cdi.MyBatisBean.create(MyBatisBean.java:115)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:761)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:861)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:375)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:386)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector$1.proceed(DefaultInjector.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:172)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:73)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.StatelessSessionBeanInjector.inject(StatelessSessionBeanInjector.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ejb.SessionBeanInjectionTarget.inject(SessionBeanInjectionTarget.java:140)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.injectEJBInstance(JCDIServiceImpl.java:257)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.injectEjbInstance(BaseContainer.java:1748)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:475)
    ... 67 more

严重:   javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:435)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2579)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1971)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy246.create(Unknown Source)
    at cn.ee.laboratory.laboratory.service.__EJB31_Generated__UserService__Intf____Bean__.create(Unknown Source)
    at cn.ee.laboratory.laboratory.view.UserAction.saveAction(UserAction.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter.doFilter(GzipResponseFilter.java:173)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:700)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:246)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:431)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:514)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:97)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:698)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.mybatis.cdi.MybatisCdiConfigurationException: There are no SqlSessionFactory producers properly configured.
    at org.mybatis.cdi.CDIUtils.findSqlSessionFactory(CDIUtils.java:53)
    at org.mybatis.cdi.MyBatisBean.findSqlSessionManager(MyBatisBean.java:129)
    at org.mybatis.cdi.MyBatisBean.create(MyBatisBean.java:115)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:761)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:861)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:375)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:386)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector$1.proceed(DefaultInjector.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:172)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:73)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.StatelessSessionBeanInjector.inject(StatelessSessionBeanInjector.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ejb.SessionBeanInjectionTarget.inject(SessionBeanInjectionTarget.java:140)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.injectEJBInstance(JCDIServiceImpl.java:257)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.injectEjbInstance(BaseContainer.java:1748)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:475)
    ... 67 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Ummm, it seems that you have encountered a known bug in the [MyBatis CDI](https://github.com/mybatis/cdi) module. The issue is reported [here](https://github.com/mybatis/cdi/issues/11).

You can try some tips proposed in the comments under mentioned ticket, but it still might not work.

BTW: Please notice that the library which you're using is really unstable (`1.0.0-beta3`). So you may consider trying for example a [MyBatis-Guice](https://github.com/mybatis/guice) module, since it is stable and mature (6 years old now).

Hope it helps